# sx and ternary operators --MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to right a ternary operator for my sx in MUI.

Any idea why this isn't working?

`sx={{...calendarDayColor, isSameDay(new Date(props.date), new Date(selectedDay)) ?bgcolor:'secondary.main'}}`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
sx={{
      ...calendarDayColor,
      bgcolor: isSameDay(new Date(props.date), new Date(selectedDay))
         ? bgcolor
         : 'secondary.main',
    }}
```